# "Add Custom Fields" button not responding in wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

Add custom fields button is not working from last few days. When I click on it, it doesn't add the value but after refreshing or updating the page it displays that custom field value entry for 2 times.
Website url : http://moviegore.com

Comment: Do you have more data about the problem? are you using a plugin or something like that?

Comment: Akismet Version  3.1.3 
All In One SEO Pack Version 2.2.7.1
BuddyPress  Version 2.1.1 
Contact Form 7  Version 4.2.2
GD Star Rating  Version 1.9.18
Google XML Sitemaps Version 4.0.8
Hello Dolly  Version 1.6
Jetpack by WordPress.comVersion 3.6.1
NinjaFirewall (WP edition) Version 1.4.3
Wiziapp   Version 3.2.8
YOP Poll  Version 5.7.5

Comment: Theme: Frisco for BuddyPress!

Comment: Try by disabling all plugins and then activate one by one to see which one it's causing the issue also do you see any error in the console?

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem solved. There is problem with "GD Star Rating" plugin.